# No visible @interface for 'AppDelegate' when calling another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, class

I have an implementation of a custom class like this:

```
@interface MyNotificationView: NSView
@property (nonatomic) int theid;
@end

@implementation MyNotificationView
- (void) rightMouseDown:(NSEvent *)event {
    [self markread];
}
- (void)markread {
    //call markAsRead in AppDelegate with _theid as param
}
@end
```

And then I have my AppDelegate:

```
...

@implementation AppDelegate
...
-(void)createLabel{
    MyNotificationView *view = [[MyNotificationView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
    view.theid = notification_id;
}
-(void)markAsRead:(int)index{
    NSMutableArray *arrayofdics = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"arrayofdics"] mutableCopy];
    NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[arrayofdics objectAtIndex:index] mutableCopy];
    [dic setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:1] forKey:@"read"];
    [arrayofdics replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:dic];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:arrayofdics forKey:@"arrayofdics"];
    [self createBodyWindow];
    unreadNotifications--;
    [self setNotificationMenuBar];
}
...
```

I am basically trying to add the functionality of a right click to a `NSView` so that when it is right clicked it runs a method that is within the `AppDelegate` class but it it is not working.

---

I have tried adding:

```
@property (nonatomic) AppDelegate* thisapp;
```

to `MyNotificationView`s `@interface`. And then in the `AppDelegate`s `createLabel` method adding:

```
view.thisapp = self;
```

and then in `MyNotificationView`s `markAsRead` method doing something like:

[_thisapp markAsRead:_theid];

but this throws the error:

```
No visible @interface for 'AppDelegate' declares the selector 'markAsRead:'
```

How should I properly implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your method i the AppDelegate.h file and then you can use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];` in your markread method to get a instance to your app delegate that you can use to call your `markAdRead` method on.